# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Member' and 'Member'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I got this error `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Member' and 'Member'` with my command, what the command is meant to do is to show how many messages a users have sent and their names I haven't used `<` anywhere in my code, this is probably caused by the `sorted` and it probably happens because two or more people have the same value, as the script was working before and works sometimes but keeps on stopping, how can i solve this to make the script still show even though one has the same number without changing what the script does, the `sort` is just their so that they can be sorted from high to low, [this is how it should be but it does this but then stop with that error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H83Dp.png)

```
d = defaultdict(int)
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    d[message.author] += 1
    pass
    await bot.process_commands(message)

@bot.command()
async def top_messager(ctx):
    sorted_d = sorted((value, user) for user, value in d.items())
    await ctx.send('\n'.join(f"{user}: {value}" for value, user in sorted_d))
```

Comment: `sorted()` uses ordering, what types are in your dictionary?

Comment: Some of the items in your tuples are instances of `Member`.  By asking Python to sort the list, you are asking it to compare two items of type `Member`.  In order to do that, you need to provide the appropriate comparison operators.  You probably need to just fix your `lambda`.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, `sorted` determines the proper order by using the element type's given `<` operator.  For `sorted` to be meaningful, you *must* have `<` defined for each possible pair of elements in the list.

The error message means that you have tried to compare two elements of type `Member`, but you have no corresponding `<` operator defined for that pair.  From your description, I strongly suspect that you've tried to compare the `Member` objects, rather than the corresponding message counts.

You should be able to quickly debug this by `print`ing the element types, and the types of the items of the sub-elements.  For instance:

```
for user, value in d.items():
    print (type(value), type(user))
    for idx, elem in enumerate(value):
        print('    ', idx, type(elem))
```

This should be enough to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Insert it whenever you have your `dict` in shape to check the entry structure.  For instance, at the top of `top_messenger`.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to sort `(int, Member)` tuples, Python will try to break ties between ints of the same value by comparing the `Member` objects, which it can't do.  Instead, use a key function to help sort the members, which will sort them stably (ones with the same value will have the same order as they do in the input)

```
await ctx.send('\n'.join(f"{user}: {d[user]}" for user in sorted(d, key=d.get)))
```

Comment: I wanted it to sort the value from more to the least

Comment: @MitchelleR.Lisowski `sorted` accepts an optional `reverse` argument `sorted(d, key=d.get, reverse=True)`